# search engine not going to correct url

Tags: web, search-engine

I have a site that when i search in google (ifiwereyou.co.uk) it takes me to a 123reg holding page. (it works fine in most other search engines)

This is beacause google is showing the url as 
http://ifiwereyou.co.uk 
rather than 
http://www.ifiwereyou.co.uk

Is this being caused by a missing dns entry or is there a way i can sort this ASAP?

Many Thanks
Sp

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not SEO tips.

Comment: this isnt an seo tip, but a question regarding the setup of the dns entries.  THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's your domain hosting service serving Parking Page. In the DNS settings you need to add a [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) www.ifiwereyou.co.uk for ifiwereyou.co.uk.